# Catch error when loading Celery config

Tags: python, celery, importerror

I'm trying to catch an `ImportError` from Celery's [`config_from_object`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#config-from-object) because I want the configuration to be loaded from a default module when it's not available. I tried

```
app = Celery('foo', include=['foo.tasks'])
try:
    app.config_from_object('foo_config')
except ImportError:
    app.config_from_object('foo.defaultconfig')
```

but this doesn't load the default configuration. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: Celery 3.1 apparently loads the configuration lazily. The (undocumented) `force` argument to `config_from_object` can apparently be used to suppress lazy loading.